# Detecting tailight indicators of cars while turning

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, vision

I want to predict if the the car in from of me turning left or right by analyzing the taillight indicator lamps.

Im new to opencv but I can code it up if you guys can give me some hints on how to proceed.Basically once I detect both the tailights(blinking),I can then suggest if the car is making only a left turn/right turn/or simple braking by analysing if only the left lamp is blinking/right is only blinking or both are red for brake.

https://youtu.be/XcQqjsaRRfE

Comment: What if one of the taillights is out?

Comment: This isn't a good question for this site. There really isn't a question in there that can be answered.

Comment: Please provide information on how you are detecting the car bounding box.

Comment: @John Sensebe If the tail lights are off I can just ignore it.Doesnt have to be 100% correct

Comment: @Wossname I am using deep learning to detect the boxes..So now I know where exactly the cars are in a frame

Comment: very hard task. You first have to detect a car, track the car between frames and then decide where the light is and in what state it is. Without all that you could try to detect some "blinking" colors, that's colors appearing and vanishing in some constant frequency, but that'll only work for blinking, not for brake-light etc.

Comment: Its doable, provided you break down your task into smaller ones. you can probably train haar cascade for detecting backside of a car. Then train a system to extract indicators, and then see if any of them is on. It depends on your usecase as well.. where are you planning to implement this? Are there known conditions where car can be "trapped"?

Comment: If that is your video footage you should start with getting better quality.
Crap in -> Crap out.
Try to at least get rid of those windshield reflections and clean your windshield. Befor trying to read signal lights you should first find the car. If you manage that in a robust way you can start thinking about signal lights.